# SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object when acces info of a iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, xss

I have a html page with an iFrame on another domain.

```
<iframe id="myframe"src="https://www.example.com" height="1000" width=100%>
```

I want to get some info of that website and used them on my html page. For example I want to extract the  tag and set it as title of my html.

I used this code I found on W3School

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("myframe");
    var y = (iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument);
    if (y.document)y = y.document;  
    var strHeader = y.body.getElementsByClassName("header");
```

I wrote in with IDE HelloWebFree (similar to notepad++). When I try my code within the IDE it works fine. But when I try to open it with safari, Google Chrome or Firefox it doesn't work.

I get the error:"`SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object`".

I don't need to change anything to the iframe content, I just want to read it and use it in my own html. So I don't see why it is a security issue. Why does it works within my IDE and not in the browser?

I have read a lot of post about this issue, but the most ones or more then 5 years old and not applicable anymore. someone an idea?

Answer (score 1):

The reason this happens in browsers is to protect the user's security.

It is in place to protect the user from any random website reading his personal info from his Facebook, or Banking website or whatever.

If you want to access public information from a website, then I suggest scraping it on the backend.

Comment: what do you mean by "scraping it on the backend"

Comment: You fetch the resource, parse it as html, and extract the required data, and you do this on the backend/server side as it has no such security restictions.

Comment: And how do I do that. I tried to do that with the "iframe.contentWindow", but that gives me the error

Comment: You have to write server side code, for example in php, or node

Comment: Have you an example?

Comment: https://dev.to/diass_le/tutorial-web-scraping-with-nodejs-and-cheerio-2jbh#scraping

Comment: and do you know why it works in the IDE I use? there must be a mechanism that allow it.

Comment: Probably becouse it is not a browser and they don't have to protect users from shady websites accessing their inforamtion.

Comment: do you have an example with php?